Setup Bit-bucket pipeline to deploy configs files into EFS
Our node applications are running on AWS Ubuntu servers. The config files related to the apps are currently saved only on the servers. I want to mount these configs files between efs and servers.
Apart from that it also necessary to maintain those configs files in bit-bucket. After pushing the config changes into bit-bucket, can the changes be automatically deployed to EFS?

Couldn't find a way to push the files directly to EFS using bit-bucket pipeline .For my requirement i use S3, EFS with AWS Data-Sync. using bit-bucket push the code into S3. Then using AWS Data sync , sync the files into EFS.

You can mount EFS from anywhere (provided the right configuration is in place), but one way how to do it AWS-style is to push to CodeCommit, use it as a trigger for CodeBuild which will synchronize the files. You can, of course, trigger the CodeBuild directly. You can also check-out via git from an EC2 instance/docker to the EFS volume and there are possible more ways how to do that.

Couldn't find a way to push the files directly to EFS using bit-bucket pipeline .For my requirement i use S3, EFS with AWS Data-Sync. using bit-bucket push the code into S3. Then using AWS Data sync , sync the files into EFS.
